# I have one central 300w power supply running at 5v. How can I split this into 3 equal "ports" that use 20amps each

Tags: power-supply, power, amplifier

I have one central 5v 300w power supply. I want to basically split the power among 3 different ports instead of blowing the whole 60 amp load. How can I share the power evenly.

Thanks!

Comment: What on earth are you powering? Most things (not LEDs) will self-balance somewhat.

Comment: It will be powering electronic cigarette atomizers which usually run on 20amp continuous batteries. I'm trying to eliminate the battery factor and provide continuous power.

Comment: 100W seems like a lot of power for that application

Comment: 20A is a ton of current. A quick search on Wikipedia suggests that a typical atomizer has a load of 1.5 to 3 ohms - with a 5V source, that's 3.3 to 1.6A. I doubt you need 20A.

Answer (score 3):

The current rating on a power supply is a **maximum**. If you connect the 5V supply to a 5 ohm load, you won't have 60A through your load - you'll only have 1A.

The same thing applies for multiple loads - you don't need to worry about them "splitting" the 60A evenly, because they'll all take the current that they need. As long as the three devices need a total current less than 60A, you should be fine.